# Working with base for strtol argument in C

Tags: c, binary

I've been learning C by using some book and there's some code that I don't understand regarding working with base in C programming. So, here's the code:

```
/* By default, integers are decimal */
#define GN_ANY_BASE 0100 /* Can use any base - like strtol(3) */
#define GN_BASE_8   0200 /* Value is expressed in octal */
#define GN_BASE_16  0400 /* Value is expressed in hexadecimal */

// rlength: Read length bytes from the file, starting at the current file offset, and display them in text form.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH); /* rw-rw-rw- */
    if (fd == -1)
        errExit("open");
    for (ap = 2; ap < argc; ap++) {
        switch (argv[ap][0]) {
          case 'r': /* Display bytes at current offset, as text */
          case 'R': /* Display bytes at current offset, in hex */
            len = getLong(&argv[ap][1], GN_ANY_BASE, argv[ap]);
            buf = malloc(len);
            ...
}
```

And here's the `getLong` function:

```
long getLong(const char *arg, int flags, const char *name) {
    return getNum("getLong", arg, flags, name);
}
```

And here's the `getNum` function:

```
static long getNum(const char *fname, const char *arg, int flags, const char *name) {
    long res;
    char *endptr;
    int base;

    if (arg == NULL || *arg == '\n') 
        gnFail(fname, "null or empty string", arg, name);

    base = (flags & GN_ANY_BASE) ? 0 : (flags & GN_BASE_8) ? 8 : (flags & GN_BASE_16) ? 16 : 10;
    res = strtol(arg, &endptr, base);

    return res;
}
```

This line really confuses me, and what happened after that didn't help either:

```
base = (flags & GN_ANY_BASE) ? 0 : (flags & GN_BASE_8) ? 8 : (flags & GN_BASE_16) ? 16 : 10;
```

What did it do? and why do we need this? what is `GN_BASE` ?

I can run the programs from the terminal by using the command:

```
./main file.txt r50
```

And it will give the following output like this:

```
r50: this is a text inside file.txt
```

I tried removing as many codes as possible for this example and hope it helps clear the example.

I'm sorry for asking beforehand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's result of this ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032445/whats-result-of-this-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The argument `flag` can carry other information so we *mask* what we are interested in with bitwise and-operator (`&`).  Btw, often those mutually exclusive flags are written with a left shift instead of absolute values (`1<<6`, `1<<7`, `1<<8`).
2. We *map* the value provided to something that is more convenient for use internally (0100 to 0, 0200 to 8, and 0400 to 16).
3. Finally, we provide a default value of `10` if none of those 3 base bits were found.

Comment: 1. Can you elaborate on why the author uses the bitwise and-operator there ?
2. I don't see any information about this 0100, 0200, or 0400 on the internet. What is it called ?

Comment: also, is that some ternary operator that the author used in base variable ?

Comment: 1.  0b11v11 & 0b100 == v` for the binary value `0b11v11` and the binary mask `0b100` (the 0b prefix is being added in c2023 so don't use it yet).  2.  In c,  numbers in base 8 (octal) are written with a 0 prefix (base 16, hex, is with prefix of 0x).  0100 = 0b000001000000 == (1<<6).  3. yes (expr ? true-statement : false-statement).   It's a compact way to write an if-condition, and in this case, the statements are (right) values so you can assign it to `base`.  A regular if-statement doesn't return a value (in c).

Comment: okay, thank you for the explanation. I think I get the explanation. But is there any link to learn about the left prefix thing in C ?

Comment: Any book on the language would cover it.  Here is an online reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant